# Converting mxml Rect & SolidColor to actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, mxml

I'm trying to learn how to use actionscript over mxml for flexibility. I have this simple block of mxml that I'm trying to convert to actionscript, but I'm stuck half way though

```
<s:Rect id="theRect" x="0" y="50" width="15%" height="15%">
   <s:fill> 
      <s:SolidColor color="black" alpha="0.9" />
   </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

I can convert the Rect no problem to

```
private var theRect:Rect = new Rect();
theRect.x = 0;
theRect.y = 50;
theRect.width = "15%";
theRect.height = "15%";
```

then I'm stuck on the fill. What's the most efficient way to add the SolidColor in as few lines of code as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
private var theRect:Rect = new Rect();
theRect.x = 0;
theRect.y = 50;
theRect.width = "15%";
theRect.height = "15%";
theRect.fill = new SolidColor(0x000000, 0.9);
```

The properties in MXML (`<fill>`) are just dot properties in Actionscript, and the values are what's next, so it's not too bad.

Hope that helps,
Lance

Comment: i know, i'm like that too sometimes. no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could have done that automatically, by using the compiler flag that keeps the generated actionscript files. See this [article](http://flexman.info/2008/05/27/using-compiler-argument-keep-generated-actionscript-in-flex-builder-project-to-viewstudy-these-automatically-generated-classes/) for how to use it.